# How do you say "heritage speaker" of German, in the linguistic sense of having informally learned the language growing up?

Tags: english-to-german, terminology

Does anyone know how you would say "[heritage speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritage_language)" of German, in the linguistic sense of having informally learned the language growing up? Does *Herkunftssprecher* work? Danke!

Comment: I would have no clue what a "Herkunftssprecher" is without some context but I don't know of a single word term for this concept either.

Comment: I wonder, whether that would still be a 'Muttersprachler' - but I don't know, whether linguists have a separate German term for this concept.

Comment: What's the difference between 'heritage speaker' and 'native speaker'?

Comment: @planetmaker You should read the linked wiki-article.

Comment: @paulFrost I read it. I cannot say that it provides a usable definition. By that articled it's native speaker, but I just want to use another word to make it sound... new? Scientific? Posh?

Comment: @planetmaker The very first sentence of the Wikipedia article names a difference between native and heritage languages.

Comment: Stackexchange discourages link-only-answers. It's possible to qoute in questions from a referenced site, too. The *first google hit* or the *first sentence in a wiki article* are subject to change.

Answer (score 5):

The German word is "Herkunftssprecher". See [here](https://www.uni-regensburg.de/sprache-literatur-kultur/slavistik/studieren-mit-migrationshintergrund/index.html) and [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-658-20285-9_3). It was transferred from English to German (loan translation).

Comment: I do not see “Herkunfssprecher” in your second reference.

Comment: @CarstenS Look at the preview below "Zusammenfassung".

Comment: I see, thanks. Still a strange word…

Answer (score 3):

*Herkunftssprecher* seems to be what academia is starting to use as the German equivalent of *heritage speaker*. It is not a widely known word yet.

To call it a translation seems a far stretch though, *Herkunft* (meaning *origin, provenance*) is a strange word to use here, it's not a translation of *heritage*, which would be *Erbe* or *Abstammung*. I don't see how a an immigrant's child or grandchild that is born in Germany is supposed to have a *Herkunft* in a different country, which is what *Herkunftssprecher* can be understood to imply. They probably mean *Herkunft* in the sense of social origin, namely the family in which the child grows up, but that is very open to misunderstandings. *Herkunft* is never only the family.

At the moment, I would personally probably just go with the english term *heritage speaker* and avoid *Herkunftssprecher* for now.

To make things more complicated, the German word for *native speaker* is *Muttersprachler* (literally "mother language speaker"), which also makes it hard or impossible to redefine his term to mean the language that the society in which the child grows up speaks *but not the child's mother*.

So this clearly needs new vocabulary, for both the parent's language and the surrounding society's language, and it's not as easy as it is in English. Perhaps "Herkunftssprecher" will stick after all, but at the moment, it seems like a strange translation attempt for "heritage speaker".

Comment: I haven't heard "Herkunftsprecher" so far; it seems to be a specialist term used by linguists. Probably it has become well-established in specialist groups and thus it does not make much sense to question whether is an "adequate" neologism. I agree to you that it is not a literal translation of "heritage speaker",  but nevertless it is an obvious analogy of the English original which was created by German linguists. It will  presumably never be used in everyday language.

Comment: Is it well-established? It seems like such a Verlegenheitslösung.

Comment: I am not a linguist, and I may be wrong. But I wrote *probably* well-established because my personal  "Google research" showed that the term is used as standard in professional literature. For example read this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301302576_Migration_und_Mehrsprachigkeit_in_der_Spracherwerbsforschung_Neuere_Erkenntnisse_aus_dem_Portugiesischen): *Im  Mittelpunkt  des  Interesses  stehen  vor  allem  die  so genannten Herkunftssprecher,  die  eine ihrer  Muttersprachen im Kontext  von Migration und einer  dominanten  Umgebungssprache  erworben  haben.*

Comment: *Während  der  Begriff  der Herkunftssprecher (‚heritage  speaker‘)  und die damit  verbundenen Besonderheiten zunächst in  den  USA  und  aus  der  Perspektive  von  bildungs-  und erziehungswissenschaftlichen Fragestellungen betrachtet wurden (Valdés  2014), ist diese Gruppe mehrsprachiger  Sprecher in den letzten Jahren auch in den Fokus sprachwissenschaftlicher und europäischer Forschung gerückt.* And even if *Herkunftssprecher* should be a "Verlegenheitslösung" - it is too late to replace it by any other term you would prefer. We have to accept reality.

Comment: A Google search also shows that the English "heritage speaker" is quite prevalent in German academic literature, too. Which, as I said, makes much more sense to me than using a bad translation that fits neither the meaning of "Herkunft" nor the existence of "Muttersprache".

Answer (score 0):

"Herkunftssprecher" would work considering the definition, but I have never heard it used. If you grew up with german you could simply consider it your mothertongue which would be "[Muttersprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Muttersprache)", which would make you a "[Muttersprachler](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Muttersprachler)"

Just because you don't know a language well doesn't make it any less your mothertongue